# Gulp watch and compile less files with @import

Tags: javascript, gulp, livereload, gulp-less

I'm trying to get my head around gulp to watch and compile a .less project + livereload.
I have a style.less file which use `@import`.
When i run the gulp task it doesn't seem to understand the imports. When I modify the main less file, gulp compiles the file and refresh the browser but if i modify only an import, the changes are ignored.

Here is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var prefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src('./style.less')
        .pipe(watch())
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(less({
          paths: ['./', './overrides/']
        }))
        .pipe(prefix("last 8 version", "> 1%", "ie 8", "ie 7"), {cascade:true})
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});
```

I tried not specifying the main file name in `gulp.src('./*.less')` but then all of the less files are compiled indvidually.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025995/gulp-less-not-handling-includes-properly Though it uses the Older style of gulp.run()

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Right now you are opening the single `gulp.src` file, and watching After you open the file with gulp.
The following will split the watching and src into two tasks, allowing for separate file and src watching.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var prefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('less', function() {
    return gulp.src('./style.less')  // only compile the entry file
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(less({
          paths: ['./', './overrides/']
        }))
        .pipe(prefix("last 8 version", "> 1%", "ie 8", "ie 7"), {cascade:true})
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./*.less', ['less']);  // Watch all the .less files, then run the less task
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']); // Default will run the 'entry' watch task
```

When Any of the files found with `*.less` are altered it will then run the task which will compile just the src file.
The @imports should be 'included' correctly, if not check the import settings.

Comment: I'm back. The files i was working on were all in the same folder `./`. I'm now working with files within the `./overrides/` folder. When i change the files in this folder, gulp doesn't detect the changes anymore. It works at the root level but not for nested imports. Is that not what the `paths: ['./','./overrides/']` is suppose to help with?

Comment: Is it possible to pass the specific watched file path into the "less" task and choose the "style.less" file based on the incoming path?